# WiX Preserve registry during major upgrade but remove on uninstall

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I would like to preserve all registry values (all contained within a single key) during an MSI major upgrade, but I would like the values deleted (as usual) when the application is uninstalled.

I believe I need to use [RegistrySearch](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/registrysearch.html) to achieve this, reading the values individually to properties.

I understand this can be achieved using the following markup:

```
<Property Id="EXISTINGAPIKEY">
  <RegistrySearch Id="name_of_dword"
    Root="HKLM"
    Key="Software\SomeCompany\SomeApp"
    Name="api_key"
    Type="raw" />
</Property>
```

I have now saved the value of `HKLM:\Software\SomeCompany\SomeApp\api_key` to a property called `EXISTINGAPIKEY`.

The next step is to write this value back to the registry once the upgrade has completed, but before the service (which is installed/updated by the package) is started.

So the questions are:

1. How can I write this property back to the registry after the update but before the service is started?
2. How can I ensure this only happens during an upgrade, and that the registry is cleaned during an uninstall?

A good chance that I'm over-thinking this!

Comment: Actually, you can create one custom action, which will delete the registry key with values at uninstall only and do nothing during major upgrade

Comment: Another option is to set `NeverOverwrite` for [wix component](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/component.html) with registry key and values (if you managed it inside your installer)

Comment: Thanks @PavelAnikhouski, I wouldn't even know where to start with a custom action (I'm just a PowerShell guy). I'll try using `NeverOverwrite` on the component containing the registry entries and revert!

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski this isn't quite what I'm after, I'll update the question when I get a chance (thanks again!)